# Wordpress Remove the decimal point from the number

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm unsing this plugin : https://financial-calculators.com/calculator-plugins/loan-plugin

But I want to remove the decimal point after the number.

For example: 10000.00  --> 10000

I am using Taiwan Dollar.

And here is the testing page: https://yuanbaoleasing.com/test/

How do I fix this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In plugin root
**fc-loan-calculator\js\interface.LOAN-WIDGET.js**

unminify the contents.
Find

```
b.formatLocalFloat = function (c, a, e)
```

and add e=0; in the first line of function

```
b.formatLocalFloat = function (c, a, e) {
  e=0;//add this line
  .....//rest of the code
}
```

This sets the precision to 0 for floating values ( refer **fc-loan-calculator/src/common.LIB.gpl.js** file FC.formatLocalFloat function to understand )

(Minify it and save as interface.LOAN-WIDGET.js) and place it inside the child theme or your custom plugin dir. The below example I provided is for custom plugin.

In child theme (functions.php) or custom plugin

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'callback_wp_footer');

function callback_wp_footer() {
        wp_deregister_script( 'fc-loan-interface' );
        wp_register_script('fc-loan-interface', plugins_url('js/interface.LOAN-WIDGET.js',__FILE__), array( 'jquery', 'wp-i18n', 'fc-custom-bootstrap', 'fc-supporting'), '', true);
        wp_enqueue_style('fc-loan-interface');
}
```

Make sure the edited js file is present in whatever path specified in wp_register_script.

**(or)**

(Not recommended way).

Just just change the js file (fc-loan-calculator\js\interface.LOAN-WIDGET.js) within the plugin fc-loan-calculator itself.

Hope it helps.